# How to setup multiple stores on different domain in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am working on magento 1.7 version.
I have a store on domain say domain1.com and it is working.
Now I want add another domain as a multiple store say domain2.com
I created website,store,storeview from admin and change base url of newly created store(domain2.com).
I copied index.php and .htaccess file from domain1.com to domain2.com root folder.

And add following lines in .htaccesss file of domain2.com:-

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website 
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2 
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

And index.php file of domain2.com is:-

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

But when I run domain2.com it gives me error like:-

```
/home/httpd/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php was not found
```

Please help me sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hosting issue - domain2.com doesn't look to be pointing to the same folder as domain1.com.

You can link folders on linux like this:

```
$ cd /home/httpd/vhosts/
$ ln -sf domain1.com domain2.com
```

Comment: That depends on your hosting setup. See above for an example.